# vscode terminal cursor issue(Using zsh and agnoster theme)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, text-cursor

I change Visual Studio Code terminal from git shell to bash shell. My bash shell is using zsh and agnsoter theme. when I open terminal in vscode command cursor position is so long.

My problem is like follows.

[image]
[image]

And My vscode configuration about terminal is like follow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Preferences -> Settings -> User Settings -> Features -> Terminal -> Integrated: Renderer type

choose: dom